# How to import multiple locale json files in Vue 3 + i18n?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

This is my code, that works without problems:

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from './components/json/foo/foo_messages.json'

const app = createApp(App)
installI18n(app)

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'ru',
  messages
})

app
  .use(i18n)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

Now I need to load messages also from `./components/json/bar/bar_messages.json`. I tried to do this way:

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import foo_msg from './components/json/foo/foo_messages.json'
import bar_msg from './components/json/bar/bar_messages.json'

const app = createApp(App)
installI18n(app)

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'ru',
  messages: {foo_msg, bar_msg}
})

app
  .use(i18n)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

But it didn't work. Could anyone say how to do it?

**EDIT**: This is my foo json file

```
{
  "ru": {
    "header": {
      "hello": "Привет"
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "header": {
      "hello": "Hello"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is bar json file

```
{
  "ru": {
    "footer": {
      "bye": "Пока"
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "footer": {
      "bye": "Goodbye"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do the json files look like?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Please, see the edit.

Comment: Objects can be merged like this: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: @PeterKrebs This will not work as all top level properties (language identifiers) will overwrite other top-level properties from different sources...

Comment: @MichalLevý Look at the answers further down. For example a [recursive object merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383245/10441671). Code can always be adapted to ones needs, like keeping all properties and so on. But it is a good inspiration either way for an answer.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Ok I see, I wasn't reading all the solutions. Anyway, importing all translations into your main (and merging) is not a good solution for his use case

Comment: @MichalLevý Yes I agree. It's just that marking it as duplicate lets mee choose the question, but not a specific answer I don't think. In either case, nice idea with the `i18n` tags - have to try that myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not very scalable. Given the format of the i18n JSON messages, you need to merge the input files to something like this:

```js
{
  "ru": {
    "header": {
      "hello": "Привет"
    },
    "footer": {
      "bye": "Пока"
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "header": {
      "hello": "Hello"
    },
    "footer": {
      "bye": "Goodbye"
    }
  }
}
```

...this is definitely possible with JS but you must still import the JSON file for each component in your `main.js` which is tedious and error prone

Did you consider using vue-i18n [custom blocks](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/sfc.html#single-file-components) in your components? You can even keep the translations in external JSON files and use a custom block like `<i18n src="./myLang.json"></i18n>`

this is much better approach but if you stil want to use yours, here is a simple code how to merge all translation files (objects imported from JSON) into a single object usable by vue-i18n:

```js
// import foo_msg from './components/json/foo/foo_messages.json'
const foo_msg = {
  "ru": {
    "header": {
      "hello": "Привет"
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "header": {
      "hello": "Hello"
    }
  }
}

// import bar_msg from './components/json/bar/bar_messages.json'
const bar_msg = {
  "ru": {
    "footer": {
      "bye": "Пока"
    }
  },
  "en": {
    "footer": {
      "bye": "Goodbye"
    }
  }
}

const sources = [foo_msg, bar_msg]
const messages = sources.reduce((acc, source) => {
  for(key in source) {
    acc[key] = { ...(acc[key] || {}), ...source[key] }
  }
  return acc
},{})

console.log(messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is already a good solution, but if you assist to use .json files to translate text. Here is my solution.

Use vue-cli to add i18n dependency, it would generate all the requirement files that we need.

```
vue add vue-i18n
```

It would generate the locales folder inside src, which it stores all the translation json files.
Then it would generate couple env variable on .env file and a i18n.js file

here is the i18n.js it generates

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

/**
 * Load locale messages
 *
 * The loaded `JSON` locale messages is pre-compiled by `@intlify/vue-i18n-loader`, which is integrated into `vue-cli-plugin-i18n`.
 * See: https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-loader#rocket-i18n-resource-pre-compilation
 */
function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key).default
    }
  })
  return messages
}

export default createI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

In our main.js,  i had seen that vue has already add the component for me

```js
import i18n from './i18n'

const app = createApp(App).use(i18n)
```

*Edit
I am using vite for building vue project, the `loadLocaleMessages` does not work in my case.
I made some modification. It needs to manually import all the json files, but i did not find any alternative solution.

I also change the env variable with 'VITE' prefix, and process.env to import.meta.env.

```js
// import all the json files
import en from './locales/en.json'
import zh from './locales/zh.json'

/**
 * Load locale messages
 *
 * The loaded `JSON` locale messages is pre-compiled by `@intlify/vue-i18n-loader`, which is integrated into `vue-cli-plugin-i18n`.
 * See: https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-loader#rocket-i18n-resource-pre-compilation
 */
function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = [{ en: en }, { zh: zh }]
  const messages = {}
  locales.forEach(lang => {
    const key = Object.keys(lang)
    messages[key] = lang[key] 
  })
  return messages
}
```

```js
export default createI18n({
  locale: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```